# Adding Margin/Padding to elements with float

Tags: html, css

I have a problem of adding margins and padding to my paragraph tag. I suspect it has to do with floating my img element to the left. While maintaining the paragraph on the right side of the image, I'm trying to add both left and right padding on my p tag as it does not touch the wrapper nor the img

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <img src="about.jpg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus et neque non volutpat. Aliquam ut pharetra ante. Proin cursus aliquam posuere. Quisque vitae ligula a lectus feugiat elementum. Pellentesque sodales arcu sed tortor dapibus, ut ultricies nibh ultricies. Vivamus accumsan gravida hendrerit. Vivamus nec ornare velit, quis volutpat velit. Fusce consectetur sagittis metus, et molestie mauris consequat at. Cras fermentum, ligula at vestibulum eleifend, leo turpis cursus libero, non porttitor diam tortor eu turpis. Nulla sodales velit metus, sit amet consectetur leo dapibus vitae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.section img {
    float: left;
}

.section p {
    padding: 0 40px;
    display: inline;
    text-align: justify;
}

.section:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;    
}
```

**EDITED**

As you can see the paragraph block start at the wrapper instead of beside the image 
[View in Developer Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gboz5.png)

Comment: have you tried adding padidng to `.section p {
    display: inline;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 20px;
}`

Comment: yes of course i have tried, it would only push the first line of the paragraph by 20px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019**

Positioning elements done easier with FlexBox

similar to the design above with flexbox it can be done through like this

```css
.parentFlex {
  display: flex;
}

.childflex {
  width: 30vw;
}

.secondChildflex {
  width: 70vw;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentFlex">
  <div class="childflex"><img src="image" alt=""></div>
  <div class="secondChildflex">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem vero iure deleniti enim ratione iste, illum facilis non magni nostrum, repellendus error placeat blanditiis, veritatis quidem consequuntur molestias deserunt necessitatibus!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are running through this problem is because you have assigned `display: inline` property to the `.section p` selector. Either you have to get rid of it or use `display: inline-block`. This would solve your problem. Try this code.

```
.section p {
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.... u can see at the image i just added in the post.